# Get all Kafka Source Connectors writing to a specific topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the name of a Kafka Topic. I would like to know what Connectors are using this topic. Specifically, I need the Source Connector name so I can modify the source query. I only have access to the Confluent Control Center. We have hundreds of Connectors and I cannot search through them manually.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to write a script.

Given: Connect REST endpoint

Do: (psuedocode)

```
to_find = 'your_topic_name'

topic_used_by = []

connectors = GET /connectors
for each connector_name in connectors:
  connector_config = GET /connectors/{connector_name}
  connector_config = connector_config['config']

  if 'topics.regex' in connector_config:
     // pattern match against your topic
     if to_find.matches(connector_config['topics.regex']):
        topic_used_by.add(connector_name)
  else if 'topics' in connector_config:
     // split these on commas
     if to_find in connector_config['topics'].split(','):
       topic_used_by.add(connector_name)

print(topic_used_by)
```

From that, your HTTP client should be easy to extend to update any config value, then `POST /connectors/{connector_name}/config`

Keep in mind that neither `'topics'` nor `'topics.regex'` are **source** connector properties (they are sink connector properties). Therefore, you'd need to modify that to use whatever connector properties you do have (ideally, filtering by the connector class name). For example, the `table.whitelist` property of the JDBC Source, or `collection` in the MongoDB source, determine the topic name.

And unless you filter by class name, that would return both sources and sinks, so unless there is `"Source"`, or similar, in the name of the connector class, this is the best you can do

Also, you'd need to consider that some topic names may be set by various `transform` configurations, which could have any JSON key value in the config, so there'd be no straightforward way to search on those without at least `transform_config_value.contains('your_topic_name')`

Comment: It seems like this approach is will not be work if the topic is published from multiple kafka connect instance.

Comment: All instances in a Connect cluster share the same configurations. It won't work across unique clusters without looping over those too

Answer (score 1):

You can use feature implemented through [**KIP-558: Track the set of actively used topics by connectors in Kafka Connect**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-558%3A+Track+the+set+of+actively+used+topics+by+connectors+in+Kafka+Connect).

E.g. Get the set of active topics from a connector called 'some-source':

```
curl -s 'http://localhost:8083/connectors/some-source/topics' | jq
{
  "some-source": {
    "topics": [
      "foo",
      "bar",
      "baz",               
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't have the connector name. I only have the topic name, and I am trying to find the producer for the topic.